# What are the regulations and laws regarding monthly invoices arriving late?

Tags: payment, invoice

Cable company monthly invoice, and only cable company monthly invoice, is arriving within two days of due date.

In general, are there any state laws or regulations requiring cable companies to send invoices in a timely manner?

Comment: Which jurisdiction (country, province, principality, state etc) does your question relate to?

Comment: @RockApe New York City, but I am interested other states as well

Comment: @paulj New York City isn’t a state

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of invoice/bill.

For a credit card bill, the federal Credit CARD Act requires the due date to be at least 21 days after billing (delivered or made available online).

Additionally, while a due date may be indicated on the bill, a late payment cannot be reported to the credit reporting bureaus until it is at least 30 days past due. Although late charges are not prohibited federally (as far as I know).

---

States may have other rules concerning billing practices of other bills, especially for regulated services (gas, water, cable, phone).

In New York, cable bills are due at least 15 days from the bill's mailing date. And a late charge may not be levied if it is paid within 45 days of mailing.

> **No late charge may be imposed prior to forty-five (45) days from mailing of the bill.** A reasonable collection charge can be added to a subscriber's bill, when a subscriber pays the amount of money in arrears in lieu of disconnection of service. Such collection charge must be in compliance with Commission regulations.
>
> [...]
>
> All cable bills must itemize rates and charges. **Payment of bills is due no sooner than fifteen (15) days from mailing.**
> https://www3.dps.ny.gov/W/PSCWeb.nsf/All/0E2474A06D5A31AC85257687006F3960